# Medialayout Silent installation sp1 sql2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

My silent installation for SQL Server 2012 SP1 is failing and giving an error as below. Any ideas?

---

> TITLE: SQL Server Setup failure.
>
> SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:
>
> The specified value for setting 'MEDIALAYOUT' is invalid. The expected
>   values are:
>
> None Core Advanced Full
>
> Error code 0x84B40001.
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&EvtType=0x28498E8E%25400x2841E06E%25401204%25401

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got the same error because I had left out the '/' in front of the ConfigurationFile argument. The correct syntax is something like this:

`F:\setup.exe /ConfigurationFile=C:\setup\ConfigurationFile.ini`